# Unable to get the server value and display it in selectmenu dropdown upon page load through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Based on server value, the jquery ui selectmenu should display that value as selected. However, when that specific page loads upon clicking the targetted menu item in the accordion, it shows blank selectmenu but when I click on that menu item for the 2nd time that value shows up. I want to know how it could load it right at the first instance. Also, the value takes about 500ms to come from server that is why I am stopping my data traffic for that time approximately and then trying to load it in selectmenu so that it has the value when needed but even that doesnt work. 
Here is the html:-

```
    <td valign="top">
            <label for="cfgMethod_0">Configuration Method</label>
            <input type="hidden" class="ipv4editable" name="cfgMethod_0" id="cfgMethod_0" disabled>
            <select id="selected_cfgMethod_0">

            </select>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <label for="ipVersion_0">IP Version</label>
            <select name="ipVersion_0" id="ipVersion_0">
                <option>IPv4</option>
                <option>IPv6</option>
            </select>
        </td>
Basically, in html code the reason I am using hidden field is because thats how I am grabbing that value, requirement is not to use it as an inputbox but instead have the selectmenu show that value as selected which you will see in js code below.
 setTimeout(function(){
        configValue=$("#cfgMethod_0").text();
        console.log("***********************"+configValue);
    }, 1000);

   if(configValue === 'DHCP'){
    $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").html("<option selected>DHCP</option><option>static</option>");
    }
    else if(configValue === 'static'){
       $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").html("<select><option>DHCP</option><option selected>static</option></select>");
    }
    else{

    }

    $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").selectmenu({
        width: 250,
        disabled: true
    });

    $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu({
        width:250,
        disabled:true
    });

    /*initialize buttons*/
    $("#editFields").button({
        disabled:false
    });

    /*disabling cancel and apply buttons by default*/
    $("#cancelButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });
    $("#applyButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });



    // Enable the editing of IP configuration 
    $(document).on("click","#editFields",function(){

            $("#editFields").button("option","disabled",true);
            $("#applyButton").button("option","disabled",false);
            $("#cancelButton").button("option","disabled",false);
            $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);

            if(tab_id === 0) {

                /*For 1st tab*/
                var connMode = $("#selected_cfgMethod_0 :selected").text();
                if (connMode === 'DHCP') {



                } else {

                }

            } else {

                /*For 2nd tab*/

                }

            }

        });



    $(document).on("click","#cancelButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");
            if(tab_id === 0){
                $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
                $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }
            else{

            }
    });

    $(document).on("click","#applyButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");

            if(tab_id === 0){
                $("#selected_cfgMethod_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
                $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }else{

            }

    });

    $(document).on("selectmenuchange","#selected_cfgMethod_0",function(){
        if($("#selected_cfgMethod_0 :selected").text() === "static") {
           $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else{
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

            $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');
```

There are two tabs actually with same options, thats why you will see tab_id comparisons but our purpose here it doesnt matter thats why I have removed that code from here.

Here is the code snippet in another js file for loading this page through accordion :-
 //here when accordion main menu item opens this is the first menu item in the submenu and that is why this has to get loaded right then

```
else if(currentlyActive===3){
        page_id = 4;
        sub_id = 1;
        tab_id = 0;
        loadAjaxData2();
        $("#protocolParameters").load("/protected/mgmtIntfcEthernet.html?tokn=" + sessnID);
        if (console !== undefined) {
            console.log($("#networkId li:first-child").text());
        }
        $(".innerMenuItem").removeClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
        $("#networkId li:first-child a").addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");

    }
```

//this is that part when you actually click on that submenu item in case you are on some other sub menu item within the same main menu item . i have to click on this 2nd time to see the value

```
 else if ($(this).text() === "Ethernet") {
        // page_id = 2;
        sub_id = 1;
        tab_id = 0;

        $("#protocolParameters").load("/protected/mgmtIntfcEthernet.html?tokn=" + sessnID);
        loadAjaxData2();
    }
```

Comment: You cant have a `<select>` inside a `<select>`: `$("#selected_cfgMethod_0").html("<select><option>DHCP...")`

Comment: @PatrickEvans : take a look at my code again I dont have multiple selects in my .html()

Comment: ohh i have it in my else part let me fix that and get back to you. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Didn't say it did, was just showing that you were doing something that is invalid html markup. As for your loading of data you do realise [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is async, you are trying to use data that hasnt been loaded yet. _"I am stopping my data traffic for that time approximately"_ not sure how you are doing that since js is single threaded. You have to pass .load a callback

Comment: @Patrick Evans: is there a way i could let the page load but delay the loading of selectmenu till I have that value. Basically I am talking about configValue variable. It seems the page loads first and then it tries to get that configValue and so when I click on the submenu item second time it then grabs that

Comment: Yes look at the documentation page for .load, it shows how to use a callback function to be used when loading of ajax requests are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105061/discussion-between-rajat-bansal-and-patrick-evans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the callback that was needed in the load. The value is taking almost 1 second to come from server so I am reloading the page again as a callback after 1.6 seconds

```
$("#protocolParameters").load("/protected/mgmtIntfcEthernet.html?tokn=" + sessnID , setTimeout(function(){
            $("#protocolParameters").load("/protected/mgmtIntfcEthernet.html?tokn=" + sessnID);
        }, 1200));
```